# How to search multiple patterns that appeare sequentially via RegExp in Javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, search

Imagine a case to search a very big file that contain 1000 sequences of A, B, C, D, E. Please note that A-E are in order and it never happens that E comes before A. I can use four basic RegExp statements to match 1000 times each A, each B, each C, each D, or E ending up 5 times reading the entire file from first to last. But, it makes lot of overhead and should be inefficient. I need to be able to read the entire file only once.For each of 1000 set of A,B,C,D,E I want to first find A, then continue reading the file to match B, C, D and E then again A, B, C, D, E ending up all searches in 1 time only.

Please note that pattern for A, B, C, D or E are different and should not be mixed. We cannot use same pattern for all. Suppose pattern for finding A is "/Jac.+/", for B is "/\d+/", for C is "/[\d\s]+/" and so on.

Let me give an example. Imagine a text file consists of information of 1000 participants in a study.

text = My name is A. I am B years old. I am studying in class C, I am from D. I have E children.

and the above 5 sentences are repeated for 1000 times. So something like

text = My name is A. I am B years old. I am studying in class C, I am from D. I have E children. My name is A. I am B years old. I am studying in class C, I am from D. I have E children. My name is A. I am B years old. I am studying in class C, I am from D. I have E children. ....

where values of A-E are different for each case.

Can I use '|' (or) to search for all A, B, C, D and Es as the reading starts from top of the file?

**Update:** 
Here is the snippet I have for matching the code:

```
var patt = /(?:"tag_A\">[\w\s\:\d\_\-\+\,\']+ | "tag_B\">[\w\s\-\d\,\'\&\;\(\)] + | "tag_C\">[\w\s\-\d\,\'\&\;\(\)] | "tag_D\">\,\s\d+" | "tag_E\">\d+)/ig;
var result = text.match(patt);
```

when I run the above code, it finds only all As. When I shuffle their order and use

```
var patt = /(?:"tag_B\">[\w\s\-\d\,\'\&\;\(\)] + | "tag_A\">[\w\s\:\d\_\-\+\,\']+ | "tag_C\">[\w\s\-\d\,\'\&\;\(\)] | "tag_D\">\,\s\d+" | "tag_E\">\d+)/ig;
var result = text.match(patt);
```

the results are all As, Bs, and Cs. No Ds no Es.

What I figures out by changing the order of RegExp in patt, I get different results. But, I have no idea that what makes this differences. When I match them separately, the RegExp are working fine meaning that they are not incorrect.

Comment: the obvious question is... have you tried it?

Comment: yes but it does not work.Though I am still working on it.

Comment: Is your file delimited into lines where you can search each line one by one?  Or is is just one giant stream of text with no delimiters?  I ask because if you can break the input into some sort of searchable unit as you read it, then you can just search for each of the multiple patterns on each searchable unit and thus avoid reading the file multiple times.

Comment: The file is an html code that has various types of tag and text in it. Can we do anything for that?

Comment: you need to post code you are attempting to use , along with sample data. A demo in jsfiddle.net or plnkr.co would also help. Nobody is going to write this for you

Comment: OK, I will put the code here as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer you probably want but here goes.

Generally:

Regular expressions are a first-come/serve proposition in order of reading from left to right.
This does not say say that some engines don't have the capability to do fuzzy/partial matching,
and can do matching from right to left (*cough* Python).

At any instance in time, there is only the current search position, there is nothing else.
If you give the engine alternatives, from *that* position, they are checked independently from
each other. *The position only changes* when one of those alternatives fully satisfy a particular
condition in its entirety.

Regular expressions are *scoped* as well.

These are the tenant's (pillars) of regex.

Armed with this information, you can combine separate regex into a single regex with  *sub-expressions*.

You prioritize the sub-expressions from left to right.
Example:  (?:`A1 B1 C1 D1 | A2 B2 C2 D2 | A3 B3 C3 D3`)

There is a drawback to this though - if the subexpressions can't be prioritized.
The problem then becomes you will encounter overlapping match possibilities.
And, in that case would *NOT* give satisfactory results.

Comment: Thanks, If I understood correctly, I can use REGEXP instead Ai-Di, isn't it? I don't know the constant values of A-D and it is the RegExp to search and fetch them for me.

Comment: I did use the (?:A | B | C| D ), but it matches only 3 of the choices instead of 4. Initially it was matching only 2 of them, then I changed the order and it showed 3, not I have to work around to get it match all 4 strings. I try to put the code for your folds to better understand my problem. Many thanks